# gitlab migrate DB but db/schema.rb not change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, centos, gitlab

i have just updated gitlab (source code) from 7.6 to 7.7.2 but something wrong.

i followed this link : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/7.6-to-7.7.md

with steps :

1. checkout version : **7-7-stable** (before, i run checkout -- db/schema.rb)

when checkout version done, i see in **db/schema.rb** have version :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150116234544) do
```

and table : protected_branches have columns as :

```
create_table "protected_branches", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "project_id",                          null: false
    t.string   "name",                                null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "developers_can_push", default: false, null: false
  end

  add_index "protected_branches", ["project_id"], name: "index_protected_branches_on_project_id", using: :btree
```

2. run command migrate database

bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

when i run above command, i see this file db/schema.rb don't contain column developers_can_push in this table protected_branches. and  version of this file is :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150812080800) do
```

so, when i start again gitlab, nginx, i don't push to gitlab server because something wrong - **this column developers_can_push not exist.**

Please help me resolve this problem.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here, check if this will work.

clipchamp.com/transcode

> never the less after trying the db:migrate:status again, it shows all migrations as 'up' after a gitlab-ctr stop and start gitlab is now working!

Comment: i have already tried db:migrate:status - all is done but when start gitlab, nothing work.    up     20141217125223  Add owner to application
   up     20141223135007  Add import data to project table
   up     20141226080412  Add developers can push to protected branches
   up     20150108073740  Create application settings
   up     20150116234544  Add home page url for application settings

Comment: yeah. I did restart gitlab.